# How can i install only ubuntu on my ssd and keeps my hdd untouched?

Tags: partitioning, grub2, hard-drive, ssd

I have 120 GB ssd and 1 TB hard drive on my laptop, currently i have my windows installed on ssd but i want to install ubuntu on my ssd and delete windows but i want my hdd untouched as i have important files there. So please help in this regard any kind of video or in depth explanation will be appreciated as i am newbie in this.
Thanks.

Comment: Safest way to protect your hard drive is to unplug it before installing.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. During install, do not allow automatic partition. You will see icon where you can designate disk drive, create partitions. You can be sure second drive is not altered.

If you are a beginner, I suggest do not choose LVM, just standard partitions. Make at least 3 partitions, one for / , /home, and /boot. These are called mount points in the installer. I would use ext4 format for drives, old standard. Some programs like Dropbox will require ext4.

The /boot partition may be unnecessary. Or it may be created automatically by ubuntu if it is a uefi install. In old days, boot partition was required always, now maybe it need not always be separate. The / partition should be around 30 or 50 GB. / is "everything" except files you put in /home or such. You want /home separate so you can erase OS and keep your docs. Almost always new users will erase OS and try again. If you make a boot partition, it should be big enough to hold 2-3 kernels.  I would guess 7GB is ample. You want to keep several kernels. In case the there is trouble with an update, you can reboot and choose previous versions.